# ymin and ymax for discrete axis in geom_area

Tags: r, ggplot2

To benchmark different groups vs the whole population I'm trying to add the population box of the population boxplot to the plot. When the axis is numeric this is easily achieved by means of `geom_area` and `geom_hline`:

```
m <- median(mtcars$mpg)
Q1 <- quantile(as.numeric(mtcars$mpg), c(0.25))
Q3 <- quantile(as.numeric(mtcars$mpg), c(0.75))

ggplot(mtcars, aes(x=cyl, y=mpg))+
geom_rect(aes(xmin = -Inf , xmax = Inf , ymin = Q1 , ymax = Q3  ),fill = "blue", alpha = .002)+
geom_hline(yintercept= m,colour = "white", size=1) + scale_x_discrete(breaks=(factor(mtcars$cyl))) + geom_boxplot(aes(group=cyl))+ coord_flip(xlim=c(3,9)) +
 geom_point() + theme_classic()
```

[image]
With a factor on the x-axis `xmax=Inf` and `xmin=-Inf` doens't work (which can be expected):

```
m <- median(esoph$ncases)
Q1 <- quantile(as.numeric(esoph$ncases), c(0.25))
Q3 <- quantile(as.numeric(esoph$ncases), c(0.75))

ggplot(esoph, aes(x=agegp, y=ncases))+
geom_rect(aes(xmin = -Inf , xmax = Inf , ymin = Q1 , ymax = Q3  ),fill = "blue", alpha = .002)+
geom_hline(yintercept= m,colour = "white", size=1)  + geom_boxplot(aes(group=agegp))+ coord_flip() + geom_point() + 
theme_classic()
```

This works but is not what I want. I want the area to cover the whole plot. Also the colour of the area is different compared to the colour on the first plot (probably related with the behaviour of `alpha`)?

```
ggplot(esoph, aes(x=agegp, y=ncases))+
geom_rect(aes(xmin = min(agegp) , xmax = max(agegp) , ymin = Q1 , ymax = Q3  ),fill = "blue", alpha = .002)+
geom_hline(yintercept= m,colour = "white", size=1)  + geom_boxplot(aes(group=agegp))+ coord_flip() + geom_point() + 
theme_classic()
```

Solutions/suggestions?

Comment: What happens when you move `xmin` and `xmax` outside of `aes()`? Since you aren't mapping them, they shouldn't be in there.

Comment: No problem! Feel free to write that up as an answer yourself and accept it, just to wrap this up.

Comment: Any idea how to keep the colour constant over different plots when using `alpha`?

Comment: If you can't know ahead of time how much overlapping will happen with the shapes you'll be using `alpha` with, then no.

Comment: Ok +1. But I can't go lower than 0.002, else the area disappears (in the answer plot).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like Joran says, just put the `geom_area` data outside of `aes`. Logical because you aren't mapping.

```
m <- median(esoph$ncases)
Q1 <- quantile(as.numeric(esoph$ncases), c(0.25))
Q3 <- quantile(as.numeric(esoph$ncases), c(0.75))

ggplot(esoph, aes(x=agegp, y=ncases))+
geom_rect(xmin = -Inf , xmax = Inf , ymin = Q1 , ymax = Q3  ,fill = "blue", alpha = .002)+
geom_hline(yintercept= m,colour = "white", size=1)  + geom_boxplot(aes(group=agegp))+ coord_flip() + geom_point() + 
theme_classic()
```

[image]